imagecreatefromjpeg produces weird corrupted images with missing colors
A very basic code to retrieve and resize images produces corrupted images, the corruption seems to happen straight from imagecreatefromjpeg (imagecreatefromstring produces the same result)
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg( "./original.jpg" );
imagejpeg($image, "./result.jpg");

Here is the original image, which in any other program shows correctly:

And the resulting image:

What is wrong with the original image, why is gd not able to read it correctly? Can I do something on php's side to fix this issue (You can download the image from SO, I just checked and it gives the same result)

The GD lib works with sRGB color space. The color space of your input image is Adobe RGB / ProPhoto RGB. So you will have to somehow convert it - probably beforehand, if you want to keep using just the GD lib, I don't think that has tools to handle this. ImageMagick might be a better choice.

Thanks to your input I will convert to using imagick then, I will post a solution later when I'm back to my laptop, or feel free to write one that I might accept it

As pointed out in the comments, GD simply doesn't know how to handle any other color space than sRGB
So I switched to using imagick, I converted my resizing function to the following code, which produces the expected output
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImageBlob(file_get_contents($original));

$image->thumbnailImage($max_width, $max_height, true);

$image->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(75);
$image->stripImage();
$image->writeImage($filename);

